# Homework: Population mean inference with unknown standard deviation

Tags: self-study, variance, population

I am doing my homework on population mean inference with unknown standard deviation, and I hope I could use your help with this one particular problem:

> *During one week in January, OfficeMax offered a 100-pack of CD-ROMs. The number of packages was limited, and no rain checks were issued. In all OfficeMax stores, 2,800 packages were in stock. All were sold. A random sample of 122 buyers was undertaken. Each was asked to report the total value of the other purchases made that day. Estimate with 95% confidence the total spent on other products purchased by those who bought the CD-ROMs.*

A table of data is  provided, listing all CD-ROM sales and all fax machine sales (other product purchases) made that day by the sample 122 buyers. In order to estimate the mean of other products purchased, I understand I would need to find out the sample variance, but this is also where I am stumped. There are 122 records of CD-ROM sales and 144 records of fax machine sales in the included data sheet, which I assume means some of the 122 buyers purchased more than one fax machine. How should I apply the formula 
$$s^2=\frac{\sum x_i^2 - \frac{(\sum x_i)^2}{n}}{n-1}$$
into solving for the sample variance? The data table did not specify which customers purchased more than one fax machine.

Comment: You seem not to have enough relevant data. Buyers could have bought much more than CD-ROMs and fax machines.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2011/09/tale-of-two-tests.html) blog post by Dave Giles will be (at least somewhat) relevant. He discusses testing for equality of means under unequal variances. See especially the paragraph starting with "Now, let's look at Questions 3 and 4." and a few paragraphs onwards.